# Что не так с моим кодом? audio.GET (VK API)

Tags: vkontakte-api

Авторизуюсь по URL:

```
https://oauth.vk.com/authorize?client_id=(СКРЫТО)&display=popup&redirect_uri=http://w-0rld.ru/index.php&response_type=code
```

Получаю токен:

```
if (isset($_GET['code']))
{
$token = file_get_contents("https://oauth.vk.com/access_token?client_id=(СКРЫТО)&client_secret=(СКРЫТО)&redirect_uri=http://w-0rld.ru/index.php&code=".$_GET['code']);
$token_GET = json_decode($token);
$token = $token_GET->access_token;
$id = $token_GET->user_id;
setcookie("token",$token,time()+3600); // Ставим куку на час ибо через час код будет не рабочим.
setcookie("id",$id,time()+3600);
header("Location: /");
}
```

Пока все гладко, но как начинаю получать аудио:

```
if($_GET['json'] AND $_GET['mode'] == 'audios')
{
header('Content-Type: application/json');
$list = file_get_contents('https://api.vk.com/method/audio.get?owner_id='.$_COOKIE['id'].'&count=81&access_token='.$_COOKIE['token']);
exit ($list);
}
```

Вылазиет ошибка:

```
{"error":{"error_code":15,"error_msg":"Access denied: no access to call this method","request_params":[{"key":"oauth","value":"1"},{"key":"method","value":"audio.get"},{"key":"owner_id","value":"171166379"},{"key":"count","value":"81"}]}}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

С кодом все впорядке, вам же сам API говорит, о том что "нет доступа к вызову данного метода". Заходим в официальную документацию API, находим [метод](https://new.vk.com/dev/audio.get) и там читаем следующее:

> Требуются права доступа: audio.

Следовательно, в авторизационный запрос требуется добавить scope, так как нужно запросить разрешение на использование

```
&scope=audio
```

Более подробно об правах доступа и параметрах авторизации, которые пригодятся при дальнейшей разработке описано в официальной документации в разделе [авторизация сайтов](https://new.vk.com/dev/auth_sites)

Comment: Пропустил пункт в доках. Спасибо за быстрый ответ!